# How to draw a random sample from a Poisson distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, probability, distribution, poisson

I have a number `X` of integers (very large) and a probability p with which I want to draw a sample `s` (a number) from `X` following a Poisson distribution. For example, if `X = 10^8` and `p=0.05`, I expect s to be the number of heads we get.

I was able to easily do this with random.binomial as:

```
s=np.random.binomial(n=X, p=p)
```

How can I apply the same idea using `random.poisson`?

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply `p` and `X`:

```
np.random.poisson(10**8 * 0.05)
```

The probability to get more than 10**8 is numerically zero.

Professor @pjs emphasizes that we are combining probability and number into a rate which is the parameter of the Poisson process.

Further worth mentioning that for such a large number you'll find the pmf's of Binomial and Poisson very similar to each other and also (using probability function or "cdf" as engineers call it) to a Gaussian.

Answer (score -2):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html

```
 import numpy as np
 s = np.random.poisson(size=n, lam=p)
```

Comment: Where did the 5 and 10**4 come from?

Comment: I copied it from the example in the numpy docs - now fixed it :)

Comment: I hope you realize that the rate (`lam`) is not a probability.